# Exit/Enter Block Agent is not undefined

Tags: simulation, anylogic, agent

I want to create new agents after the cutting (delay Block). I tried to use the exit and enter Block.
I get this Error: The method take(Agent) is undefined for the type Main._enter_Population

My Agents have no parameters in the Population, is this the problem? I write the code in the Enterblock and nothing in the Exitblock.

This is the code:

```
Agent Ober=add_materials();

enter.take(Ober);
```

Comment: where is your enter block located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to create new agents after the cutting (delay Block).

To create a new agent, you can write `add_myAgent()` into your "on Exit" code of the delay block, assuming there is an agent population `myAgent` in the same agent as the delay block, and it has no parameters.

Else, you can also use the "Split" block after the Delay, it can be set to create new agents:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the code in the exit block like `myEnterBlock.take(agent)`

This will move the exiting agent into whatever `myEnterBlock` block.

> My Agents have no parameters in the Population, is this the problem?

no, completely irrelevant

> I want to create new agents after the cutting (delay Block)

This is yet again fully independent of using Enter/Exit blocks, so maybe open a new question on this :)

Comment: First of all, thank you! But in which Block schuld i write that they add a new agent?